# Laravel project UML Class diagram

Tags: php, laravel-4, uml

I have been googling around for UML examples for MVC PHP Framework as well as a project UML Diagram to do with a PHP project but unfortunately java and c# examples always come up.

I have a small understanding of UML diagrams but not real example to see hwo it is used. I have a laravel project which I am working on and I want to create a UML class diagram to show the class i am using.

In java and PHP i know one of the ways to know if a class is associate with another is when it is getting instantiated in another class with the key word **new**

what I want to know is in laravel hwo do you know when a model or controller is associate with each other or another. I have asked in one of the community channels and someone told me "it is not really linked" which doesn't answer my question. What I want to know is if i do something like  `User::where('username', '=', $username)->where('active', '=', 0)->get();` in a controller does this mean that the controller is now associated with the User model or the controller is a dependency of the User model?

e.g.

[image]

What I am confusing about is another a UML class diagram will look like for any laravel or PHP MVC application.

Thanks

Comment: I would say User Model is a dependency of the controller. The relationship will be Controller uses Model to get works done. Not sure if this answers your question, but just some thoughts.

Answer (score 3):

You can show the relation between both by using a role name at each side of the association. The role name is placed "on the other side" of the association. So if `AccountController` uses `User` as `currentUser`  then place the role name `currentUser` near the `User` attached association.

An example for the role use is this:

[image]

The class diagram will not tell you anything about instantiation itself. Rather you use a sequence diagram to show that. E.g. (without knowing anything about your domain) if `AccountController` creates a `User` object it will send a `new` message which tells that a `:User` instance has to be created. Termination can be shown by a `X` at the end of the life line of an object.

And the instances of these classes are used in a SD as follows:

[image]

The first message is the `new` message. The messages below use some of the operations you stated in your classes (no idea if that makes sense). The final `X` indicates the termination of `:User`