# Laravel MVC application structure on UML class diagram

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, uml, class-diagram

As shown in many examples, MVC architecture involves three classes - Model, View and Controller respectively. With this, it is simple to show MVC on UML class diagram.
However, in Laravel the view is not a class directly, it is a page. Can you please tell me, how to display a such a view on UML class diagram properly? (or, if there is no way, on another UML diagram)

**Edit** My current attempt looks like this: [image]

Comment: Who told you the view should be a class? MVC is just  pattern. It says nothing about implementation

Comment: I understand. However, mostly view is shown as a class in examples (I refer, mostly, to Java+Swing experience). And, because of this, it is easy to show pattern structure on class diagram. However, with view being a page, the V component is missing on a diagram, at least I have no idea how to visualise its presence.

Comment: In these cases I represent them as a resource, this resource is used internally by a class (the view class controller thingy). It's just something you are not creating yourself

Comment: For laravel: here is your view class: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/View/View.php The template is just a resource used by your actual class

Comment: Could you please give me a simple example of displaying a resource?

Comment: there is more then a class diagram in UML, for instance a Component.

Comment: So, in this case we do not mention views on class diagram?

Comment: I understand the way how Laravel works. What puzzles me is how to represent this on diagrams.

Comment: Depends on what you are trying to represent in the UML diagram. Skip the MVC buzzword. Are you trying to create a diagram of your code? or of laravel? ...

Comment: I'm trying to create a diagram of my code. For instance, I have User model, UserController with typical CRUD methods (index, show, update, destroy, etc.) and typical pile of views (index.blade.php, show.blade.php, etc.).

Comment: Please show what you have created so far and ask for critique.

Comment: The point is that I'm doing a project at the university and it is required to mention patterns which I use and show how they are applied in my project using UML. Hence, I need to show how MVC affects the structure of my project on class diagram.

Comment: Thomas, it looks somewhat like this https://www.dropbox.com/s/tv6wkuby3nldwd0/2015-06-09_22-53-34.png?dl=0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply present a view as a class. Dialog elements can be shown as attributes having types that can be either simple strings (for input fields) or other classes that represent e.g. drop down.

**Edit** Your diagram looks ok. Just add the attributes for the view like

```
+email:Text
+password:HiddenText
+name:String
+OK:Button
```

etc.

Comment: What naming should I use for naming class after a view? Does it matter much?

Comment: It does not "really" matter. Naming conventions vary. Doesn't Laravel have its own ones?

Answer (score 0):

I struggle with this as well. Its hard to make a good class diagram for a PHP Laravel project. besides that, MVC is a pattern and has little to do with instantiation of classes. So I don't think a class diagram is the way to go.

I instead find it a lot better to use a sequence diagram to map your project out.

like this, suggested on another feed:
[sequence diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEwjy.png)

[Laravel project UML Class diagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29222425/laravel-project-uml-class-diagram)

I hope this helps!